# Закрытие соединения с файлом

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Я не могу понять где я неправильно высвобождаю ресурсы/закрываю файл.
Везде использую using, но все равно исключение что файл уже используется другим процессом

```
public class DownloadControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUpdateFile _updateFile;
    public DownloadControllerBase(IUpdateFile updateFile)
    {
        _updateFile = updateFile;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFilesBase(
        int userID,
        string folderForDownloadCryptedFiles,
        string zipFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string encryptedFilesFolder = Path.Combine(folderForDownloadCryptedFiles, $"User({userID})");
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(encryptedFilesFolder);

            if (files.Length == 0)
                return StatusCode(404, new { message = BaseErrorMessage.DownloadNoFiles });

            string zipFilePath = Path.Combine(encryptedFilesFolder, zipFileName);
            await CreateZipFile(userID, zipFilePath, files);

            return await DeleteZipAndCreateResponse(zipFilePath, zipFileName);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            return StatusCode(404, new { message = BaseErrorMessage.FolderNotFound });
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateZipFile(int userID, string zipFilePath, string[] files)
    {
        using var zipStream = new FileStream(zipFilePath, FileMode.Create);
        using var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry(fileInfo.Name, CompressionLevel.Fastest);

            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                await fileStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
            }
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            await UpdateFile(userID, fileName);

            await Task.Run(() => System.IO.File.Delete(file));
        }
    }

    private async Task UpdateFile(int userID, string fileName)
    {
        var DbData = new UserFileModel()
        {
            user_id = userID,
            file_name = fileName,
            status = Status.downloaded.ToString(),
            download_time = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        await _updateFile.UpdateFileByNameOrID(DbData, "fileName");
    }

    private async Task<IActionResult> DeleteZipAndCreateResponse(string zipFilePath, string zipFileName)
    {
        using var stream = new FileStream(zipFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        await Task.Run(() => System.IO.File.Delete(zipFilePath));

        return File(stream, "application/zip", zipFileName);
    }
}
```

Вот так вызывается этот метод в контроллере:

```
    [HttpGet("Download")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFiles([FromRoute] string type)
    {
        try
        {
            var param = _cryptographyParams.GetCryptographyParamsNoKey(type, FuncType.encrypt.ToString());

            return await _downloadController.DownloadFilesBase(_userInfo.UserId, param.downloadFolder, "EncryptedFiles.zip");
        }
        catch (InvalidRouteException ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(404, new { message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Лог исключения:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\FileCryptWeb Users\Private\Encrypted files for download\User(22)\EncryptedFiles.zip' because it is being used by another process.
         at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
         at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
         at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
         at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
         at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
         at FileCryptWeb.Controllers.BaseControllers.DownloadControllerBase.CreateZipFile(Int32 userID, String zipFilePath, String[] files) in C:\Users\Stewi\Source\Repos\air2921\FileCryptWeb\FileCryptWeb\Controllers\BaseControllers\DownloadControllerBase.cs:line 51
         at FileCryptWeb.Controllers.BaseControllers.DownloadControllerBase.DownloadFilesBase(Int32 userID, String folderForDownloadCryptedFiles, String zipFileName) in C:\Users\Stewi\Source\Repos\air2921\FileCryptWeb\FileCryptWeb\Controllers\BaseControllers\DownloadControllerBase.cs:line 31
         at FileCryptWeb.Controllers.CryptionControllers.EncryptionController.DownloadFiles(String type) in C:\Users\Stewi\Source\Repos\air2921\FileCryptWeb\FileCryptWeb\Controllers\EnryptionControllers\EncryptionController.cs:line 94
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at FileCryptWeb.JwtTokenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, FileCryptDbContext dbContext, ITokenService tokenService) in C:\Users\Stewi\Source\Repos\air2921\FileCryptWeb\FileCryptWeb\JwtTokenMiddleware.cs:line 47
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Ну вот в `DeleteZipAndCreateResponse` вы открыли стрим из файла и тут же пытаетесь удалить этот открытый файл ))  Я честно говоря не знаю как такое разруливать, но удалять файл в этот момент как-то рановато ))  Стрим его явно лочит. Это же поток, это не так, что из него всё считалось и можно забыть про этот файл.

Comment: Я почему-то этого совершенно не учелл. Мда уж. Спасибо за такую очевидную подсказку

Comment: Может дело и не в этом, но это то, что бросилось в глаза сразу. Не знаю, может тут можно просто прочитать весь файл и закрыть стрим. И после этого удалять. Но я так понимаю вы хотите именно потоком файл отдавать, тогда так не получится, наверное. Если он так правда отдаётся потоком наружу, я просто не очень знаю как веб часть работает.

Comment: До этого отдавал архив как массив байтов, но там уж было слишком страшно за OutOfMemEx, сейчас пытаюсь отдать архив как поток, но столкнулся с этой проблемой. Только что-то попробовал удалять файл в блоке finally, но это ситуацию не исправило.

Comment: Честно говоря, не представляю что делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я уже написал в комментарии, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь удалить файл, который открыт для стриминга.

Я нашёл [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43981710/8324991) на английском SO. Можно задать флаг `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`, чтобы файл, который стримится, удалился после использования автоматически.

```cs
private async Task<IActionResult> DeleteZipAndCreateResponse(string zipFilePath, string zipFileName)
{
    var stream = new FileStream(zipFilePath, FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);

    return File(stream, "application/zip", zipFileName);
}
```

Остальные параметры прописаны просто чтобы нужный метод вызвался, с этим параметром, там и остальные параметры нужно указать.

Comment: Выглядит как хорошее решение, но только вот теперь вылезает другое исключение  System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file. Я честно говоря перестаю понимать в чем дело, и как это можно пофиксить. Возможно ошибка в другой части приложения, но навряд ли, сейчас дополню вопрос.

Comment: А, стоп, в ответе, из которого я стырил, нету `using`. Попробуйте без него ))  Уберу `using` из ответа, хотя может и не в этом дело.

Comment: Ну в таком случае это работает, но тут вспылывает другой вопрос, что на счет высвобождения ресурсов, закрытие файла это конечно вопрос риторический, ибо нет файла, нет соединения с ним. Но использует ли FS какие-то ресурсы диска, которые нужно высвобождать ?

Comment: @air Ну, в данном случае стрим точно знает, что ему нужно удалить файл, я думаю он при этом не забывает и все ресурсы освободить )  Почитайте доку на `FileStream`, возможно там этот аспект явно описан. Но вообще не знаю, как-то нехорошо, что `using` нельзя использовать. Увидеть бы полный стек-трейс ошибки...

Comment: Читал доку, ничего про ресурсы не сказано, сказано только про закрытие потока.

Comment: Здесь не стоит переживать, что `using` не используется, т.к. инфраструктура ASP.NET Core самостоятельно уничтожает файловый поток связанный с возвращаемым FileStreamResult после отправки ответа. Это упоминается в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (см. секцию _Комментарии_ под методом с соответствующей сигнатурой). Перевод, правда, оставляет желать лучшего, под _удаляется_ имеется ввиду _уничтожается_ (_disposed_ в оригинале).

Comment: @i-one О, спасибо за наводку, и правда "The fileStream parameter is disposed after the response is sent.", и это логично.